# Pass parameter into Python function

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I have a function that accepts a [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) object, `soup`.

I also want to pass it a variable telling it what to do with `soup`. Right now the function is:

```
def get_info(soup):
    info = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'hideinse'})[0]('a',href=True)
    #do stuff
```

But what I want to do is pass in this line `findAll('div',{'id':'hideinse'})[0]('a',href=True)` and not as a bunch of strings.  I want it not to always be `findAll` and such, so want I'm trying to do but not sure how is:

```
def get_ifno(soup, parse_line):
     info = soup.parse_line
     #do stuff
```

So how can I pass that in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the complexity of what you want you should take a function in that the caller can provide:

```
def get_info(soup, parse_line):
    info = parse_line(soup)

get_info(soup, lambda x: x.findAll('div',{'id':'hideinse'})[0]('a',href=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can probably get the most flexibility with the least amount of headache by passing lambdas:

```
def get_info(callback):
    info = callback()

get_info(lambda: soup.findAll('div',{'id':'hideinse'})[0]('a',href=True))
```